# Why am I getting a "Microsoft JET Database Engine" popup when I click save in my app?

Tags: c#

I am creating an application to add entries into a database, but when I click <kbd>Save</kbd> I get a popup window that says "Microsoft JET Database Engine" and nothing else.  Now I'm fairly new to programming and so I don't know what this means.  I've tried looking it up but all I find is various error codes with JET Database Engine in them.

I'm using C# for creating the app and the database was created using Access 2013.

Below is a portion of the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace ParkingDatabase
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    OleDbConnection Connect = new OleDbConnection();
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\bkoso\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ParkingDatabase\ParkingDatabase\ParkingData.mdb";
        Connect.Open();
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("Insert Into Guest Info(Guest First Name, Guest Last Name, Room Number, Departure Date, Return Date, Vehicle Colour, Vehicle Make, License Plate Number, Contact First Name, Contact Last Name, Contact Phone Number, Contact Email, Park And Fly Tag Number) Values(@Guest First Name, @Guest Last Name, @Room Number, @Departure Date, @Return Date, @Vehicle Colour, @Vehicle Make, @License PlateNumber, @Contact First Name, @Contact Last Name, @Contact Phone Number, @Contact Email, @Park And Fly Tag Number)", Connect);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Guest First Name", txtBxGstFName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Guest Last Name", txtBxGstLName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Room Number", txtBxRm.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Departure Date", txtBxDDate.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Return Date", txtBxRDate.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vehicle Colour", txtBxVColour.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vehicle Make", txtBxVMake.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@License Plate Number", txtBxPlate.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact First Name", txtBxContactFName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact Last Name", txtBxContactLName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact Phone Number", txtBxPhone.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact Email", txtBxEmail.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Park And Fly Tag Number", txtBxTag.Text);

        if (Connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            try
            {
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Guest Information Saved Successfully");
                txtBxGstFName.Text = "";
                txtBxGstLName.Text = "";
                txtBxRm.Text = "";
                txtBxDDate.Text = "";
                txtBxRDate.Text = "";
                txtBxVColour.Text = "";
                txtBxVMake.Text = "";
                txtBxPlate.Text = "";
                txtBxContactFName.Text = "";
                txtBxContactLName.Text = "";
                txtBxPhone.Text = "";
                txtBxEmail.Text = "";
                txtBxTag.Text = "";

            }
            catch (Exception notSaved)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(notSaved.Source);
                Connect.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: It looks like that's coming from your `catch` block.

Comment: Exactly, If you change the content of your MessageBox.Show from notSaved.source to notSaved.ToString() you could have more info about what it's failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely encountering an error in your `btnSave_Click` method.

The `catch` block in your `try... catch` section is displaying a message box with the `Source` of the error, and not the error `Message`.

```
catch (Exception notSaved)
{
    MessageBox.Show(notSaved.Source);
    Connect.Close();
}
```

Change this section as follows, so you can show the user the actual error message.

Also, attempt to close the connection only if it is not null and is not already closed. Otherwise you will get an exception inside an exception :)

```
catch (Exception notSaved)
{
    if (Connect != null && Connect.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
         Connect.Close();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Error saving data \n" + notSaved.Message);
}
```

Comment: Hey Shiva thanks for the reply.  Your suggestion gave me the error "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" which apparently means I have reserved words in in my column names.  Now I changed the names of my table columns as the support article on Microsoft suggested but I'm still getting the error.  Could I still be getting this error even if some of my column names have one of the reserved words in it, even if it is combined with another word?  Exampled Date is a reserved word, but I'm using it as DepartureDate & ReturnDate.  Could this be causing the error?

Comment: No, column names that contain reserved words won't cause a problem. According to you code, you have column names with spaces in them. I'm not certain how Microsoft Jet handles those but you should try to avoid them if possible.

Comment: This is a different question though. @Bloodstalker you need to post your SQL statement so we can see what could be wrong. Without that, hard to tell. Still, that should be a separate question. This question was resolved by my answer, right?

Comment: Thank you for your help Shiva and I apologize for posting the second question here, I'm new so I didn't realize I should separate the questions.  And yes your question solved the original problem.  Thank you.  I will post the new question a bit later.

Comment: No worries. And I see that you posted the other question separately and got instant feedback and were able to fix it and move on. Good luck on your learning :)